# Connect to BlazeDS with java stand alone app

Tags: java, air, blazeds

I have a java server with a BlazeDS interface to handle Adobe AIR clients.  I also have a bunch of legacy stand alone java apps that I'll need to integrate with the server.  The java apps need all the same methods and remote calls that the AIR clients needs.  So it would save tons of work if I could call the remote object methods from the java apps.

Anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BlazeDS Java AMF libraries directly over HTTP. But interacting with the BlazeDS MessageBrokerServlet will require some extra work.  Probably an easier path is to just expose the same Java services through another protocol that the Java code can more easily use.

Comment: You mean something like webservices, Axis2 or similiar?

Comment: Sure.  Anything that will serialize the data and provide easy APIs for accessing it.  AMF is best for Flex clients because it's fast.  But it's normal to provide additional serialization options to the same service objects.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [this](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Java+AMF+Client) library, it allows you to connect Java with a server running BlazeDS. On the other hand if you are interested in pure performance you can [investigate](http://wiki.github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/) another protocols..there are plenty of them.